# Design question for a table with too many joins OR polymorphic relations in Postgres 11.7

Tags: postgresql, join, polymorphism, data-warehouse

I've been given a table that I'm not sure how to design. I'm hoping for some design suggestions, or pointers in the right direction. The table is called `edge` and is meant to store some event traces, and IDs that link out to a host of *possible* lookup tables. Leaving out everything but IDs, here's what the table contains, all UUIDs:

```
ID
InvID
OrgID
FacilityID

FromAssemblyID
FromAssociatedTo
FromAssociatedToID
FromClinicID
FromFacilityDepartmentID
FromFacilityID
FromFacilityLocationID
FromScanAtFacilityID
FromScanID
FromSCaseID
FromSterilizerLoadID
FromWasherLoadID
FromWebUserID

ToAssemblyID
ToAssociatedTo
ToAssociatedToID
ToClinicID
ToFacilityDepartmentID
ToFacilityID
ToFacilityLocationID
ToNodeDTS
ToScanAtFacilityID
ToScanID
ToSCaseID
ToSterilizerLoadID
ToUserName
ToWasherLoadID
ToWebUserID
```

That's an overwhelming number of IDs to possibly join on. I remember reading that the Postgres planner kind of gives up when you've got a dozen+ joins. The idea being that there are so many permutations to explore, that the planning time could quickly overwhelm the query time. If you boil it down, the "from" and "to" links are only ever going to have one key value across all of those fields. So, implemented as a polymorphic/promiscuous relations, something like this:

```
ID
InvID
OrgID
FacilityID
FromID
FromType
ToID
ToType
ToWebUserID
```

This table is going to be ginormous, so speed is/will be a consideration.

I encouraged the author *not* to use a polymorphic design, although the appeal is obvious. (I like Karwin's *SQL Antipatterns* book.) But now, confronted with nearly three dozen IDs, I'm a bit stumped.

Is there a common solution to this kind of problem? Namely, where you've got a central table like this with connections to a wide variety of possible tables? I don't have a Data Warehousing background, but this looks somewhat like that. (The author of this table has read Kimball's books, but not done any Data Warehouse implementations either.)

Important: We're using `JOIN` to do lookups on related values that might change, we're *not* using it to change the size of the result set. Just pretend it would always be `LEFT JOIN`.

With that in mind, what I've thought of is to skip joining on the `From` and `To` IDs, and instead use custom function calls to look up required values from the related tables. like (pseudo-code)

```
GetUserName(uuid) : citext
...and os on for other values of interest in this and other tables...
```

The function would return '' when the UUID is 0000etc.

I appreciate that this isn't the crispest question in the history of SO, and I what I'm hoping for pointers in a fruitful direction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This smacks of “premature optimization” (which is a source of evil) based on something that you “remember reading”, so maybe some enlightenment about join optimization will help.

One rule of thumb that I follow in questions like this is to model things so that your queries become simple and natural. Experience shows that that often leads to good performance.

I assume that the table you show is the fact table of a star schema, and the foreign keys point to the many dimension tables, so that your query will look like

```
SELECT ...
FROM fact
   JOIN dim1 ON fact.dim1_id = dim1.id
   JOIN dim2 ON fact.dim3_id = dim2.id
   JOIN dim3 ON fact.dim3_id = dim3.id
   ...
WHERE dim1.col1 = ...
  AND dim2.col2 BETWEEN ... AND ...
  AND dim3.col3 < ...
  ...
```

Now PostgreSQL will by default only consider all join permutations of the first eight tables (`join_collapse_limit`), and the rest of the tables are just joined in the order in which they appear in the query.

Moreover, if the number of tables reaches the threshold of 12 (`geqo_threshold`), the *genetic query optimizer* takes over, a component that simulates evolution by mutation and survival of the fittest with randomly chosen execution plans (really!) and consequently doesn't always come up with the same execution plan for the same query.

So my advice would be to write the queries in a way that the first seven dimension tables are the ones with the biggest chance of reducing the number of result rows most significantly (based on the `WHERE` conditions). You can also increase `join_collapse_limit`, because if your queries take a long time to run anyway, you can easily afford the planner to spend more time thinking about the best plan.

Then you'd set `geqo = off` to disable the genetic query optimizer.

If you design your queries according to these principles, you should be able to get good execution plans without messing up the data model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for including the specifics for the behavior I only read about in passing. (And for the settings, which simplifies me digging in for more details.) Postgres is *vast*, so folks like you that know where everything is are a real help.